# Changing shortcode on wordpress child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, function, accordion, shortcode

I'm trying to change an Accordion shortcode in the parent theme to include h-tags but I'm running into problems with redeclaring errors.

Here's the original code in the parent theme's accordion.php:

```
// [accordion]
function ux_accordion($atts, $content=null, $code) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'auto_open' => '',
        'open' => '',
        'title' => ''
    ), $atts));
    if($auto_open) $open = 1;
  if($title) $title = '<h3 class="accordion_title">'.$title.'</h3>';
  return $title.'<div class="accordion" rel="'.$open.'">'.flatsome_contentfix($content).'</div>';       
}
add_shortcode('accordion', 'ux_accordion');


// [accordion-item]
function ux_accordion_item($atts, $content=null, $code) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'title' => 'Accordion Panel',
    ), $atts));
    return '<div class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="accordion-title plain"><button class="toggle"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></button><span>' . $title . '</span></a><div class="accordion-inner">'.flatsome_contentfix($content).'</div></div>';
}
add_shortcode('accordion-item', 'ux_accordion_item');
```

What I've tried to do is here:

```
// block accordion firing from parent theme
function remove_parent_accordion() {
    remove_shortcode('accordion');
    remove_shortcode('accordion-item');
}
add_action('init', 'remove_parent_accordion');

// [accordion]
function ux_accordion($atts, $content=null, $code) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'auto_open' => '',
        'open' => '',
        'title' => ''
    ), $atts));
    if($auto_open) $open = 1;
  if($title) $title = '<h2 class="accordion_title">'.$title.'</h2>';
  return $title.'<div class="accordion" rel="'.$open.'">'.flatsome_contentfix($content).'</div>';       
}
add_shortcode('accordion', 'ux_accordion');

// [accordion-item]
function ux_accordion_item($atts, $content=null, $code) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'title' => 'Accordion Panel',
    ), $atts));
    if($title) $title = '<h3 class="accordion_item_title">'.$title.'</h3>';
    return '<div class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="accordion-title plain"><button class="toggle"><i class="icon-angle-down"></i></button><span>' . $title . '</span></a><div class="accordion-inner">'.flatsome_contentfix($content).'</div></div>';
}
add_shortcode('accordion-item', 'ux_accordion_item');
```

This results in "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare ux_accordion_item() " Not sure what I'm doing wrong. By right if the shortcode remove function fires there shouldn't be a problem right?

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You have to give you functions different names for e.g `function ux_accordion_item` should be changed to `function myprefix_accordion_item` and then update the `add_shortcode` to `add_shortcode('accordion-item', 'myprefix_accordion_item');`. The same goes for the other shortcode

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more than one function with the same name even if they are not being called/used.  You can use either `if(function_exists('function_name'){}` if you want to avoid the fatal error but your function will not be executed if another function is already registered with the same.

In your case you can just change the function name with a custom prefix. For e.g `function ux_accordion_item` should be changed to `function myprefix_accordion_item` and then update the `add_shortcode` to `add_shortcode('accordion-item', 'myprefix_accordion_item');`. The same goes for the other shortcode.

Comment: Be aware that ˋadd_shortcode()ˋ asks wordpress to execute the function when it encounters the shortcode in the blog text. So maybe use a different shortcode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried changing the function name to an alternative. e.g. function my_accordion. However, when I call 'add_shortcode('accordion', 'my_accordion')' , the page loads but the accordion basically shows up as the shortcode. i.e. somehow the code doesn't work. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Additional info: If I used add_shortcode('my-accordion', 'my_accordion_item'), it does work but all the CSS and other things relating to the original 'accordion' shortcode is gone. I would want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: In `ux_accordion` it seems you are only changing the h3 tag to h2. You do not need to overwrite the shortcode function, you can just style it with ur custom css i think no?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I have never heard of altering an html tag using css though. That is why I would rather purge the parent functions and replace them with the child theme functions

Comment: You can leave it as h3 but in your css target the h3 to have the same styling as h2: `h3.accordion_title{}`